# Plotly show axes borders in all subplots using template

Tags: templates, plotly

I have the following code to define my custom template:

```py
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

boring_thesis_template = pio.templates['simple_white']
for xy in {'x','y'}:
    boring_thesis_template.layout[f'{xy}axis'].update(
        dict(
            mirror = 'allticks',
            ticks = 'inside',
            showline = True,
        ),
    )
pio.templates['boring_thesis_template'] = boring_thesis_template
pio.templates.default = 'boring_thesis_template'
```

Everything is fine until I use it with `marginal` like this:

```py
fig = px.ecdf(
    reconstruction_error.sample(9999),
    marginal = 'histogram',
    title = f'Reconstruction error distribution<br><sup></sup>',
)
```

which produces:

[image]

As seen, the y borders of the top plot are missing. How can I construct the default template in such a way that it does not miss those borders?

Comment: Modifying the template to the following code made no change.
The template does not have a second axis set up, so it may be necessary to duplicate the first axis to accommodate this. `boring_thesis_template.layout['yaxis2']=dict(anchor='x2', matches='y2', showline=True)`

Comment: If you are only dealing with the outputs in your question, the following code will give you the intended result. `fig.update_layout(template='plotly_white', yaxis2=dict(showline=True));
fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True);
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)`